# MAUI CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement Issue with .net7

Tags: xamarin, maui

I have installed *CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement* with my project that has migrated to .net7 from .net6
and used "**using CommunityToolkit.Maui;**" reference and "**.UseMauiCommunityToolkitMediaElement()**"
within **MauiProgram.cs**.but occurred the below error. How to solve that?

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'MauiAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseMauiCommunityToolkitMediaElement' and no accessible extension method 'UseMauiCommunityToolkitMediaElement' accepting a first argument of type 'MauiAppBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  TestApp (net7.0-android)    C:\Users\esh\source\repos\TestApp\src.TestApp.mobile\MauiProgram.cs 23  Active

Comment: Did you try to delete the `/bin` and `/obj` folder of your project and rebuild it ?

Comment: @Poulpynator.yes I have done it several times.

Comment: My only guess is that some dependencies are still pointing on .NET 6 and some on .NET 7, with `CommunityToolkit.Maui v5.0.0` and `CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement v1.0.2` it's working fine for me in a new .NET 7 project